# How to find control id for dropdown that triggered OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several dropdowns that all trigger the same OnSelectedIndexChanged event. Once the OnSelectedIndexChanged event fires, I'd like to know the id of the dropdown responsible for triggering the event.

Is there a way to pull this info into a string?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="updateView">
   <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Not Started</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Submitted</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>WIP</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Not Applicable</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Rejected</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="updateView">
   <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Not Started</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Submitted</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>WIP</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Not Applicable</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Rejected</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void updateView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string dd_id = id of dropdown that triggered this event;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sender` is the control that actually triggered the event. You can try this:

```
protected void updateView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    string dd_id = ddl.ID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, this is just what I was looking for. Works perfectly. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the system lets me.